# What is the best way to import sass partials with webpack while still keeping styles together?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-component

I need to import sass partials in Vue single file components. Since Sass imports may cause duplicate output, I'm importing via webpack in the script block. Everything works great, but I find it problematic from a maintenance standpoint that my sass partials are so far from the rest of my styles in code. This is mainly a question of style and organization.